# which version of tomcat is compatible with Java 1.6

Tags: java, tomcat, java-6

Friends I need to configure my project with JDK 1.6 version.In this project I have to use tomcat server which version of tomcat is compatible with Java 1.6.

Answer (score 3):

Tomcat 6.0 (see [Release Notes](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/RELEASE-NOTES.txt))